# prevent Devise user from accessing/editing forms through the URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've all the necessarily steps in the views and controllers to prevent users from editing forms that does not belong to them. However, if user A goes directly to the site using the url (for ex: **journey/5/trips/new**) it will still allow user A to create a new trip under journey 5, even though the journey 5 belongs to user B.

What is the best way in rails to deal with this situation? I am using devise 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the trips controller you can add a `before_filter` method to check whether a journey belongs to `current_user` or not

```
before_filter :authorize_journey, only: [:new]

def authorize_journey
  @journey = current_user.journeys.where(id: params[:journey_id]).first

  if @journey.blank?
    flash[:error] = "You cannot access someone else's record."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!